# Does "Rebase before delivery" cover all merge conflicts?

Tags: merge, clearcase

Assuming I have a parent stream and a child stream. There are no other active streams.
If I rebase child stream to parents' recommended baseline, resolve all conflicts and then deliver from the child to parent - does it mean that I NEVER encounter conflicts when I deliver after that rebase?

I'm trying to realize if 'rebase before delivery' covers ALL merge conflicts between two streams.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I rebase child stream to parents' recommended baseline, resolve all conflicts and then deliver from the child to parent - does it mean that I NEVER encounter conflicts when I deliver after that rebase?

Yes, you shouldn't, unless there is a deliver from the same stream, but from a different view (by another developer, and you have somehow missed the update).

If you are alone working on the child stream, rebase then deliver is the best practice.
It ensures you update your stream and your view first, resolve any conflict locally (and check them in on your child stream) before delivering your baseline to the parent stream.

Note that the baseline from the parent stream doesn't have to be a "recommended" one, it just has to have been created on the parent stream (for a direct child stream to be able to rebase it).